# Ruby sqlite3 gem installation issue on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I am very new to ruby and rails. I am trying to install to sqlite3 for trying a tutorial and having issues. I am on Windows 10 and using `ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x64-mingw32]`.

Here is the installation error I am getting while running `gem install sqlite3-ruby`. I have also tried running `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=c:/sqlite3/include --with-sqlite3-lib=c:/sqlite3/lib`

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190217-3116-1d59gcv.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-dllib
    --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I have downloaded sqlite3 from their site and here is the folder structure of `C:\sqlite3\`

```
sqldiff.exe
sqlite3.exe
sqlite3_analyzer.exe
include\shell.c
include\sqlite3.c
include\sqlite3.h
include\sqlite3ext.h
lib\sqlite3.def
lib\sqlite3.dll
```

I have also copied `sqldiff.exe, sqlite3.exe and sqlite3_analyzer.exe` to `C:\Ruby26-x64\bin`.
In my environment variable, I have added `C:\sqlite3\` to `PATH` and also created a new environment variable `sqlite3-dir` pointing to `C:\sqlite3\`

Could someone please provide some help for this installation problem?

Comment: Do you need the most actual version? I had also problems with sqlite3 1.4.0, but version 1.3.13 worked fine for me. `gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.13`

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue using these steps in this link: https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/241

Comment: Perfect timing for this question. I am learning Ruby on Rails and just got this error on my first project.

Comment: someone put that link in a comment. Don't know why that comment was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding `gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"` in the project Gemfile file works. After that run `bundle install`. Make sure to install git in the machine. This is the [github link](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/241)

Answer (score 2):

This is what has currently worked for me and it's a per project fix; Samiul Alam Anik's answer, but with an addition. After you follow those steps, you might get a `requires Bundler 2` and this is solved for me with `gem update --system` thanks to this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6937).

Answer (score 1):

For solving this issue for all the projects I downloaded the gem file from https://rubygems.org/ and saved it locally, installed MinGW by cmd

```
C:\Sites>ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
```

and the SQLite 3 gem after

```
C:\Sites>gem install --local C:\sqlite3-1.4.0.gem
```

and it worked for all the next projects created on Sites folder if you need to fix a project already created trying running `bundle install` again after those lines.

I also tried including the SQLite 3 files to the path but it didn't work for me either

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have current Ruby version installed on your computer, install node ja, install yarn, update npm, update gem Ruby.

```
C:\Users\adilkemo>ruby --version 
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\adilkemo>gem --version  
3.2.15

C:\Users\adilkemo>node --version  
v16.4.2

C:\Users\adilkemo>yarn --version  
1.22.10

C:\Users\adilkemo>npm --version   
7.18.1

C:\Users\adilkemo>sqlite3 --version  
3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39 5c9a6c06871cb9fe42814af9c039eb6da5427a6ec28f187af7ebfb62eafa66e5

C:\Users\adilkemo>gem install rails 

C:\Users\adilkemo>rails --version  
Rails 6.1.4

C:\Users\adilkemo>cd Desktop  

C:\Users\adilkemo\Desktop>rails new blog  

C:\Users\adilkemo\Desktop>cd blog  

C:\Users\adilkemo\Desktop\blog>bin/rails server - Goodbye!
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y  

C:\Users\adilkemo\Desktop\blog>
```

https://rubyinstaller.org/
https://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/
https://nodejs.org/en/
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/getting_started.html

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Please understand the purpose of the edit notice field. Please double check that I did not break anything in your post, my intention was only to your info into the right shape, not to participate in this community wiki post (because I am surprised that you chose to make this one).